# Why stacktrace is not displayed when an exception occurs?

Tags: .net, exception, error-handling, stack-trace

I have a problem. My program crashes on start up without any stack trace. The only thing I can see is "Send Report To Microsoft". This happens only on one PC.

Can you explain me **Why some exceptions are with stack trace and some are without?**

Thanks.

Comment: Is the application compiled in Debug or Release mode? What is the .NET Framework and the OS version? What happens if you try to save the stack trace for every exception, ie. use a global `try/catch` block and save the exception trace before terminating the application?

Comment: Release mode;  .Net Framework 3.5; Windows XP German; Global try/catch doesn't get any results..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No stack traces are shown for unhanded exceptions by default.

If a suitably installed debugger is configured (e.g. Visual Studio installed normally) then you will be prompted to start a debugger session when an program crashes, otherwise the "send report" option is displayed.

Anything else is in the implementation of the program.

I would suggest looking at something like [`procdump`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx) (Sysinternals) to capture a memory dump from which VS can give you a stack trace (and more details) to help diagnosing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that the application is crashing before loading the .Net framework and executing your Main() function.

I'd suggest either checking the event viewer, or running it under a debugger such as windbg.